# Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

Hi all we have develope an J2EE application which can execute the stored procedure to get data from databases. 
Previously it was working fine before we ***upgrade our MySql Version to 5.5 to 5.6*** 
now I am getting `Communications link failure during commit()` also I am not sure that this error is due to upgrade of mysql or not. I have allready spend a week to solve this problem.

**NOTE:** *Also when I restart my application and mysql it will work fine for some times then it started to giving following exception.*

**Framework We Use**

```
Spring 3.0.1
Hibernate 3.3
```

Just Upgraded Following things

```
C3P0 (Previous Version 9.1.2)
c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar 
c3p0-oracle-thin-extras-0.9.5-pre8.jar
mchange-commons-java-0.2.7.jar
Connector/J (Previous Version 5.1.7)
mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar
```

**C3P0 Configuration**

```
initialPoolSize=10
maxPoolSize=30
minPoolSize=5
acquireIncrement=3
acquireRetryAttempts=0
preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1
idleConnectionTestPeriod=600
numHelperThreads=10
testConnectionOnCheckout=true
maxIdleTime=300
```

**JDBC proprities**

```
DriverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true&autoReconnect=true
Username=root
Password=
```

**Error Message**

```
ERROR org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction#toggleAutoCommit  - Could not toggle autocommit
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor56.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3009)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2895)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3438)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1951)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2548)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4916)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:912)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.toggleAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:194)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commitAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:115)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:412)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:625)
        at com.report.service.servk$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$dd20ff76.l(<generated>)
        at com.report.controller.contbg.c(UserDashboardController.java:296)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.report.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:69)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.report.filter.GUIDFilter.doFilter(GUIDFilter.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2455)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2906)
```

When I execute following query to check open connection with my database

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE DB = "mydatabase";
```

It shows me all the queries executed by my application as follows

```
| ID  | USER     | HOST            | DB         | COMMAND | TIME | STATE               |INFO                      | TIME_MS | ROWS_SENT | ROWS_EXAMINED |
| 881 | root     | %:59283         | mydatabase | Query   | 1483 | Creating sort index | MY Query in Stored Procedure | 1482838 |         0 |             0 |
...
20 rows in set (0.42 sec)
```

I gone throw following links but still not able to get the solution

**[Automatic reconnect from Hibernate to MySQL](http://www.databasesandlife.com/automatic-reconnect-from-hibernate-to-mysql/)**

**[Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)**

Can any one help to solve this problem or any helpfull link or steps to debug will be appreciated

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: have you checked the server log? it looks like the autocommit was sent but then something happened, possibly a server crash...

Comment: @Jess Balint thanks for your reply... Yes I know something happening but how can I know this happening thing...?

Answer (score 1):

Network instability

reappear code:

`con.query()
sleep(10) //when sleep shutdown your network 
conn.roolback()`